# matrix with ill condition in a linear regression, what would happen when inversing it? what can we do and how it can help?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When we are working on linear regression and we find that the X matrix is in ill-condition (i.e. the smallest eigenvalue of X'X is very close to zero) which might cause serious numerical problems when you take the inverse.

How can we fix/improve it? Why would it help?

Comment: One common strategy is to use [preconditioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner). For example, [Jacobi preconditioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner#Jacobi_(or_diagonal)_preconditioner) could be useful here.

Comment: Thanks! it looks like it is for solving a linear system. What if one would like to find a good approximate of its inverse, do you have any recommendation?